# JavaScript File Transfer SSH

Tags: javascript, ssh, yaml, sftp, scp

I'm currently working on a browser based project where I'm using JavaScript, HTML and CSS for the first time, having had no past experience with these languages. Basically the project involves the following: (1) allowing the user to upload a .csv file via the following code:

```
    <input id="files" type="file" accept=".csv" />
```

(2) Reading the file, (3) converting to a YAML file (.yml) and (4) uploading it to a remote server via SSH/SCP/SFTP.

I've done (1) and (2)  but what I'm having real trouble with is part 4. My questions are:

- is it possible in JavaScript to upload a file to a remote server via SSH/SCP/SFTP, keeping in mind that this is a browser based project.
- if no, what are some alternative browser based methods of allowing a user to do this?
- any good resources on making .yml files using JavaScript?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't think of anything right now, off the top of my head. If I do I will post another idea :)

Comment: I have a Javascript build process written as an `HTA` file -- web page that runs with app level permissions -- that calls out to an external FTP program to upload things.  it is hard to use the windows built-in FTP client because the people who wrote that didn't include a passive mode.

Comment: You have only XMLHttpRequest API (for HTTPS and FTP) and WebSocket API (for WSS). so in 2017 there is no way to do "SSH/SCP/SFTP" directly.

Answer (score 1):

Security in client-side JavaScript is a flawed idea and due to this it's unlikely that you will find JS-based SSH implementation (SSH is quite complex protocol family). The best options are either to have a Java applet to do the job (the applet must be properly digitally signed to be allowed to connect to third-party location) or upload the file to the web server and have it upload the file elsewhere.

Comment: Can you please expand on the websever idea? Thanks.

Comment: @AliKhokhar SFTP file upload must take place on the server rather than in the client browser. I you have the data on the client, post them back to the server and let the server do SFTP.

Comment: I’ve resorted to WebDAV